# how to return to previous page

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

on appbar, i want to return to previous page using icon. but it keep saying that the argument type 'context' cant be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext'.

```
AppBar app_bar_parking ({String title = ''}) { 

  return AppBar( 
    backgroundColor: Colors.white, 
    centerTitle: true,
    title: Text('Parking & Pay'), 
    elevation: 0,
    titleTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),
    leading: GestureDetector(  
      child: IconButton(  
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_new_outlined, 
      size: 20, 
      color: Colors.lightBlue,),
      onPressed: () { 
        Navigator.pop(context);
       }
    ),
    )
        
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because into your class you do not have a `context` declaration.

Add `BuildContext context` to the parameters you need.

```
AppBar app_bar_parking(BuildContext context, {String title = ''}) {
  return AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      centerTitle: true,
      title: Text('Parking & Pay'),
      elevation: 0,
      titleTextStyle:
          TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),
      leading: GestureDetector(
        child: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.arrow_back_ios_new_outlined,
              size: 20,
              color: Colors.lightBlue,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            }),
      ));
}
```

and when you use your `app_bar_parking` remember to add the context as:

```
app_bar_parking(context, "MyTitle");
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `context` in the function.

```
AppBar app_bar_parking ({String title = '',BuildContext context}) { 

  return AppBar( 
    backgroundColor: Colors.white, 
    centerTitle: true,
    title: Text('Parking & Pay'), 
    elevation: 0,
    titleTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),
    leading: GestureDetector(  
      child: IconButton(  
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_new_outlined, 
      size: 20, 
      color: Colors.lightBlue,),
      onPressed: () { 
        Navigator.pop(context);
       }
    ),
    )
        
  );
}
```

Now use inside the `build()`

```
@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     appBar: app_bar_parking('',context),
// rest of the code
   );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `BuildContext context` in your function parameter. Basically, you have to use the same context.

```
app_bar_parking ({String title = '',BuildContext context}) {}
```